# Parse json to Mongoose schema

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My mongoose schema:

```
const BillSchema = new Schema({
    fromDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    toDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    phoneNumber: { type: String },
    created: { type: Date},
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    billDetail: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BillDetail' }]
});
const BilldetailSchema = new Schema({
    amount: { type: Number },
    item: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String},
    code: { type: String},
    amount: { type: Number },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

My Json get from client

```
{ billDetail: [ { item: [Object], amount: 1, rentalPrice: 11, rentalDays: 1 } ],
  code: '000001',
  customerName: 'steve',
  phoneNumber: '959494949',
  fromDate: '2017-05-07T17:00:00.000Z',
  toDate: '2017-05-18T17:00:00.000Z' }
```

How can i parse json string above to bill object? I try to use this code:

```
let bill = new Bill(req.body);
```

but it's not working, it's only returning bill, but not billdetails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`billDetail` should be an array of ids, not the objects.

You can insert bill details first, obtain their ids, and then push them to a new `billDetail` array.

```
BillDetail.insertMany(req.body.billDetail)
    .then(function(billDetails) {
         const billDetail = billDetails.map(billDetail => billDetail._id);
         const billData = Object.assign({}, req.body, { billDetail });
         const bill = new Bill(billData);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // error handling here
    });
```

Comment: it's working :D thank you so much, And what about Item, i have already created it, so, when i send object from client, i just have to push _id in to billDetail, right ?

Comment: `item` has to be an id, easier if you pass it from the client

Comment: so we can't use the schema object? we have to use the model?